# Why is paymentQueue(_:shouldAddStorePayment:_:) not being called?

Tags: ios, storekit

Why is paymentQueue(*:shouldAddStorePayment:*:) not being called?

I am sure I've done everything I need to do.

I declared my own class that supports the SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
import AudioToolbox.AudioServices

class UTIPaymentTransactionObserver: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {

        print("!!! shouldAddStorePayment")

        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)

        return false

    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        print("!!! updatedTransactions")

        for transaction in transactions {
            print("!!! transaction=", transaction)
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            // Call the appropriate custom method for the transaction state.
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchasing:
                showTransactionAsInProgress(transaction, deferred: false)
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.deferred:
                showTransactionAsInProgress(transaction, deferred: true)
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
                failedTransaction(transaction)
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
                completeTransaction(transaction)
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:
                restoreTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }

    }

    func showTransactionAsInProgress(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, deferred: Bool) {

        print("!!! showTransactionAsInProgress")

    }

    func failedTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {

        print("!!! failedTransaction")

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

    }

    func completeTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {

        print("!!! completeTransaction")

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

    }

    func restoreTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {

        print("!!! restoreTransaction")

    }

}
```

I added code to vibrate the device when paymentQueue(*:shouldAddStorePayment:*:) is called to indicate that the method is actually called.

I declared an instance of the observer class globally:

```
internal let paymentTransactionObserver = UTIPaymentTransactionObserver()
```

I made sure I added the observer in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentTransactionObserver)

    return true
}
```

The print statement in the paymentQueue(*:shouldAddStorePayment:*:) method never prints and the device never vibrates. It doesn't look like that method is called.

The paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) method is called. The print statement in that method executed.

In this code I returned false for the paymentQueue(*:shouldAddStorePayment:*:) method, but it doesn't make a difference. The process goes through just as if I returned a true. The product had already been purchased before, so it goes through and lets the user/tester purchase it again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is code extension for the view controller that retrieves the product from App Store and presents my user interface that allows the user to purchase the product:

I call validateProductIdentifiers() to start the process of selling the product to the user.

```
// MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

extension CloudViewController: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    func validateProductIdentifiers() {

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Purchase", withExtension: "plist")!

        let nsArrayProductIdentifiers: NSArray = NSArray(contentsOf: url)!

        let productIdentifiers = nsArrayProductIdentifiers as! [String]

        print(productIdentifiers)

        let setProductIdentifers: Set = Set(productIdentifiers)

        let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: setProductIdentifers)

        self.productsRequest = productsRequest

        productsRequest.delegate = self

        productsRequest.start()

    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        print("!!! didReceive")

        self.products = response.products

        let alertMessage = "Would you like to purchase?"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let actionYes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) {

            action in

            // Purchase

            let product: SKProduct = response.products.first!

            let payment: SKMutablePayment = SKMutablePayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

        }

        let actionNo = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(actionYes)
        alert.addAction(actionNo)

        alert.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = barButtonItemEnableDropbox

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you initiating the purchase? This method is only called when the use initiates the purchase in the App Store, not when you initiate the purchase in your app

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the answer to your question at the bottom of the post along with my code.

Comment: Right, so you are initiating the purchase in your app, so this delegate method won't be called as per its documentation. This method is only called when the user initiates the in-app purchase from the App Store app on their device

Comment: @Paulw11 I was sure the documentation meant that method is called when the user makes a purchase as my code allows the user to. Even though the user makes the purchase from my app, the purchase is still from the App Store. Am I misunderstanding the documentation? Are you sure you are correct? Here is where I get that information from: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/PromotingIn-AppPurchases/PromotingIn-AppPurchases.html

Comment: No, there is no need for this delegate method to be called if the purchase is initiated in your app, since you can simply not show the relevant ui. This method is called if the user purchases from the App Store app or redeems a code for an in-app purchasein the App Store app.  For example, your server may not be available to validate a purchase a receipt, so you can return false to defer the purchase to a later time

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok. I just tested the protocol to test that. As the instructions say I sent a link to myself by text message. When I tapped on the link the app opened as it should. It won't do that now. Any ideas why? Or should I post another question for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179171/discussion-between-paulw11-and-shinehahgnolaum).

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/2877502-paymentqueue) for this method

> This delegate method is called when the user starts an in-app purchase in the App Store, and the transaction continues in your app. Specifically, if your app is already installed, the method is called.

This occurs when a user redeems a promo code for an in-app purchase in the App Store app or purchases a promoted in-App purchase in the App Store app.

It is not called when the purchase is initiated in your app, since you already have control over whether purchasing should be permitted when the user is in your app.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This answer in in the "low quality answers queue" and **may** be voted for deletion. I suggest you try to expand the content detail to avoid that happening.